# So how can I update or re-render my html template on dynamically changed property using VueJS?

Tags: vue.js

I have a VueJS template with Bootstrap 4 modal dialog inside it:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="vue-case-select">

 <div class="modal fade" id="case-select" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="caseLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document" ref="container">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header"> ... </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <div class="modal-container">

        <!-- This property must be reactive and re-rendered -->
        <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="title">

       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</script>
```

And a component corresponding the template:

```
Vue.component('vue-case-select', { 
    template: '#vue-case-select',
    props: [
        'predefined_title',         
    ],
    data() {
        return {
            title: '',
        }
    },
    mounted: function() {
        // Updating current title and it works
        this.title = this.predefined_title;
    },
});
```

Everything works just fine statically. But I want to change value of the `input[type=text]` inside my dialog depending on a parent component of user's choice. I'm trying to do it this way:

```
// This code is executed in a method of another VueJS component which has
// its own title

const MyCase = Vue.extend(VueCaseSelect);
const vm = new MyCase({
    parent: this,
    propsData: {
        // Passing title to modal dialog and it works
        predefined_title: this.title,
    },
});

vm.$mount('#some-element-id');
```

I know for sure that property `title` is changed correctly on `mounted` event inside `vue-case-select` component each time I create a new `MyCase` object. But I cannot figure out how to make `input[type=text]` control update its value according to `v-model`.

So how can I update or re-render my html template on dynamically changed property using VueJS?

I have tried `computed`, `watch` and `$nextTick()` but may be I did it the wrong way?

**UPD**: May be it needs to be mentioned that this code works only once. For the first time I can see a dialog with a title shown, but when I close it and click on another component, the title variable in VueJS in correct state, but the `input[type=text]` still contains the previous title value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try to use watcher ? like this one

```
watch: {
   predefined_title(val) {
      this.title = val
   }
}
```

Or, put a condition in your input to prevent showing it when predefined_title is empty.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="title" v-if="predefined_title">
```

Or, destroy your component to remove it in the vue instance like this below

```
beforeDestroy () {
    this.$el.parentNode.removeChild(this.$el);
    $('.modal-backdrop').hide();
},
```

Comment: watch does not react on property change, but it triggers on title change. Anyway, this does not help :(

Comment: How do you trigger your dialog ?

Comment: $('#case-select').modal(); after assigning all fields in MyCase component

Comment: In watch did you see that the value of title is updating ?

Comment: Yes, title is updated every time it should and I can see it in watcher, but input value updates only once (for the first title) and keeps its value until page reload.

Comment: okay, but your $('#case-select').modal() works even many times triggering it ?

Comment: did you also used this.$forceUpdate(); ?

Comment: $('#case-select').modal(); just shows the modal dialog (using data-toggle="modal" data-target="#case-select"> - the same thing). It pops up every time I need but the input value is the same as in the very first popup (though title field changes its value correctly)
UPD: Yes, I did.

Comment: then how you change again the value of the props you passed to that dialog ?

Comment: Each time user clicks a button I create a new component const vm = new MyCase({ ... some props here ... }) with corresponding title. Title is passed as a component prop, then that component needs to update input value (v-model), but it does it only once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206726/discussion-between-qonvex620-and-peschanko).

Comment: Can you include the template code of the parent component to see how the user selection there is passed to the component code shown in the question?